# JQuery Show/Hide 1000k+ <options> Condition. How to?

Tags: jquery, select, window.location

My Goal

I am trying to create a simple "custom URL' builder, users select the company they work for, the area they needed access to, and in the end, the builder redirects them to the correct page based on their "home-institution" URL + the custom URL from their selection on the dropdown list.

The challenge

I got this to work, however, the  will have around 130 , and depending on their selection, the next div is to select the custom url page they need access to and that will open to about more 130 divs, with 10-15 options (different URLs) each, making the list about 1500+ lines.

They way I am settings this up is working just fine, but I am afraid my array of options for each possible choice they make, will be too big and not sure if I am doing is the best way to do it.

Is there a better way to store this huge array values, that will only show partially based on what their selections are?

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/to30kc7e/

````
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>jQuery Show Hide Elements Using Select Box</title>
    <style>
        .business-type {
            display: none;

        }

        .personal-type {
            display: none;

        }

        extinst {

            display: none;

        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>


</head>



<body>

    <select class="business" id='home' name='home_inst'>
        <option value='#'>Select your provider...</option>
        <option value='https://google.com'>Google</option>
        <option value='https://microsoft.com'>MicroSoft</option>
        <option value='https://apple.com'>Apple</option>
        <option value='https://nike.com'>Nike</option>
    </select>

    <select id='purpose'>
        <option value="#"></option>
        <option value="seller">Sellers Website</option>
        <option value="buyer">Buyers Website</option>
        <option value="client">Clients Website</option>
        <option value="employee">Researchers Website</option>
    </select>

    <select class='extinst' id='EXTseller'>
        <option value="/service_center/3608?tab=about" id="3608" name="Bioimaging/ Keck Division">Bioimaging/ Keck Division</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3692?tab=about" id="3692" name="Bioimaging-Electron Microscopy">Bioimaging-Electron Microscopy</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3900?tab=about" id="3900" name="DNA Lab">DNA Lab</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3897?tab=about" id="3897" name="Genomics Core">Genomics Core</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3606?tab=about" id="3606" name="Goldwater Environmental Lab">Goldwater Environmental Lab</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3701?tab=about" id="3701" name="High Pressure Facility">High Pressure Facility</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3859?tab=about" id="3859" name="High Resolution Mass Spectometry">High Resolution Mass Spectometry</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3194?tab=about" id="3194" name="IBeam">IBeam</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3193?tab=about" id="3193" name="Materials Processing">Materials Processing</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3858?tab=about" id="3858" name="MRRC-Magnetic Resonance">MRRC-Magnetic Resonance</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3966?tab=about" id="3966" name="Ultrafast Laser Facility ">Ultrafast Laser Facility </option>
        <option value="/service_center/3860?tab=about" id="3860" name="Visualization Lab">Visualization Lab</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3973?tab=about" id="3973" name="X-Ray Diffraction">X-Ray Diffraction</option>
    </select>
    <select class='extinst' id='EXTbuyer'>
        <option value="/service_center/?tab=about" id="" name="Biostatistics ">Biostatistics </option>
        <option value="/service_center/3644?tab=about" id="3644" name="Flow Cytometry">Flow Cytometry</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3646?tab=about" id="3646" name="Cellular Anatomy and Biology - Imaging Core Facility">Cellular Anatomy and Biology - Imaging Core Facility</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3716?tab=about" id="3716" name="Clinical Trials Office">Clinical Trials Office</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3721?tab=about" id="3721" name="Small Animal Behavior">Small Animal Behavior</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3713?tab=about" id="3713" name="Electron Microscopy">Electron Microscopy</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3885?tab=about" id="3885" name="Genomic-Proteomics">Genomic-Proteomics</option>
        <option value="/service_center/4008?tab=about" id="4008" name="Research Pharm.">Research Pharm.</option>
        <option value="/service_center/4007?tab=about" id="4007" name="Cancer Center Flow Cyto.">Cancer Center Flow Cyto.</option>
        <option value="/service_center/4019?tab=about" id="4019" name="Mass Spec. ">Mass Spec. </option>
        <option value="/service_center/4059?tab=about" id="4059" name="Integrated Genomics">Integrated Genomics</option>
        <option value="/service_center/4058?tab=about" id="4058" name="Proteomics and Metabolomics Facility">Proteomics and Metabolomics Facility</option>
        <option value="/service_center/4057?tab=about" id="4057" name=" Core Imaging Facility for Small Animals (CIFSA)"> Core Imaging Facility for Small Animals (CIFSA)</option>
        <option value="/service_center/4365?tab=about" id="4365" name="Immune Monitoring Shared Resources">Immune Monitoring Shared Resources</option>
        <option value="/service_center/4364?tab=about" id="4364" name="Radiology Research Core">Radiology Research Core</option>
        <option value="/service_center/4363?tab=about" id="4363" name="IRB">IRB</option>
    </select>
    <select class='extinst' id='EXTemployee'>
        <option value="/service_center/?tab=about" id="" name=" PDX/CAM"> PDX/CAM</option>
        <option value="/service_center/5174?tab=about" id="5174" name="ATC X Ray Core">ATC X Ray Core</option>
        <option value="/service_center/?tab=about" id="" name="Baculovirus">Baculovirus</option>
        <option value="/service_center/4983?tab=about" id="4983" name="BCM Data Research Technology">BCM Data Research Technology</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3851?tab=about" id="3851" name="Bioengineering">Bioengineering</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3450?tab=about" id="3450" name="BISR">BISR</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3450?tab=about" id="34000" name="BISR (2">BISR (2)</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3168?tab=about" id="3168" name="Breast Center - Histopathology Core">Breast Center - Histopathology Core</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3684?tab=about" id="3684" name="CAMRI">CAMRI</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3215?tab=about" id="3215" name="Cell Based Assay Screening Service (CBASS)">Cell Based Assay Screening Service (CBASS)</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3437?tab=about" id="3437" name="Center for Comparative Medicine">Center for Comparative Medicine</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3220?tab=about" id="3220" name="Center for Drug Discovery">Center for Drug Discovery</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3366?tab=about" id="3366" name="Center for Human Immunobiology">Center for Human Immunobiology</option>
        <option value="/service_center/?tab=about" id="" name="CFAR">CFAR</option>
        <option value="/service_center/5077?tab=about" id="5077" name="Clinical Translational Core">Clinical Translational Core</option>
        <option value="/service_center/4579?tab=about" id="4579" name="Cryo EM">Cryo EM</option>
        <option value="/service_center/2935?tab=about" id="2935" name="Cytometry and Cell Sorting Core (CCSC)">Cytometry and Cell Sorting Core (CCSC)</option>
        <option value="/service_center/?tab=about" id="" name="DDC">DDC</option>
        <option value="/service_center/?tab=about" id="" name="DNA Sequencing">DNA Sequencing</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3392?tab=about" id="3392" name="Genetically Engineered Mouse">Genetically Engineered Mouse</option>
        <option value="/service_center/2936?tab=about" id="2936" name="Genomic & RNA Profiling Core (GARP) - previously Microarray Core Facility">Genomic & RNA Profiling Core (GARP) - previously Microarray Core Facility</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3395?tab=about" id="3395" name="Integrated Microscopy">Integrated Microscopy</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3051?tab=about" id="3051" name="Mass Spectrometry Proteomics">Mass Spectrometry Proteomics</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3219?tab=about" id="3219" name="Metabolomics">Metabolomics</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3152?tab=about" id="3152" name="Mouse ES">Mouse ES</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3715?tab=about" id="3715" name="Mouse Metabolism (#2)">Mouse Metabolism (#2)</option>
        <option value="/service_center/2937?tab=about" id="2937" name="Mouse Phenotyping Core">Mouse Phenotyping Core</option>
        <option value="/service_center/5040?tab=about" id="5040" name="Neurobehavioral ">Neurobehavioral </option>
        <option value="/service_center/5064?tab=about" id="5064" name="Neuroconnectivity Core">Neuroconnectivity Core</option>
        <option value="/service_center/5041?tab=about" id="5041" name="Neurovisualization Core">Neurovisualization Core</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3090?tab=about" id="3090" name="Optical Imaging & Vital Microscopy (OIVM)">Optical Imaging & Vital Microscopy (OIVM)</option>
        <option value="/service_center/2959?tab=about" id="2959" name="Pathology Core: Histology, Vector System">Pathology Core: Histology, Vector System</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3359?tab=about" id="3359" name="Pathway Discoveries">Pathway Discoveries</option>
        <option value="/service_center/?tab=about" id="" name="Pediatric Molecular Analysis">Pediatric Molecular Analysis</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3872?tab=about" id="3872" name="Physiological Imaging Center for Translational Research">Physiological Imaging Center for Translational Research</option>
        <option value="/service_center/?tab=about" id="" name="Pluripotent">Pluripotent</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3091?tab=about" id="3091" name="Population Biosciences Biorepository">Population Biosciences Biorepository</option>
        <option value="/service_center/?tab=about" id="" name="Protein Profiling/Quantitative Proteomics">Protein Profiling/Quantitative Proteomics</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3294?tab=about" id="3294" name="RNA In Situ Hybridization @ ATC">RNA In Situ Hybridization @ ATC</option>
        <option value="/service_center/?tab=about" id="" name="Scanning EM (Nano)">Scanning EM (Nano)</option>
        <option value="/service_center/3866?tab=about" id="3866" name="Single Cell Genomics">Single Cell Genomics</option>
    </select>





    <script>
        $(".extinst").hide();
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#purpose').on('change', function() {
                var demovalue = $(this).val();
                $(".extinst").hide();
                $("#EXT" + demovalue).show();

            });

            $('.extinst').on('change', function() {
                var x = $('#home').val();
                var y = $('.extinst').val();
                window.location.href = x + y;

            });


        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>```
````